# How to reload the last cell in a section in swift

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I am trying to load a cell into a certain section of my tableView with an animation, but It is crashing giving me this error `'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to delete row 1 from section 0 which only contains 1 rows before the update'`

from this code:

```
let indexPath = IndexPath(item: session[section].count - 1, section: section)
tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
```

this code is triggered after a user clicks a button to add another cell to the end of that section. All I want to do is add that cell to the end of the section with an animation, how can I do that?

```
 @objc func addSetPressed(_ sender: UIButton){
        let section = sender.tag
        session[section].append(ExerciseSet(setID: "", sessionID: "", exerciseID: "", setIndex: section + 1, weight: session[section][0].weight, reps: session[section][0].reps))
        
        //tableView.reloadData()
        
        let indexPath = IndexPath(item: session[section].count - 1, section: section)
        tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
        
        
        setTableViewHeight()
        UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .soft).impactOccurred()
        
        
    }
```

Comment: share all code inside that action plus table data source methods

Comment: `attempt to delete row 1 from section 0 which only contains 1 rows before the update`. It means you try to delete the last one but now you want to reload it ?